# Successfully extend custom SQL Datatables with aspnet_Membership tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, sqlmembershipprovider

I have an application which I created using MVC3 and Custom SQL Database with 3 tables:
`mm_Table1`, `mm_Table2`, `mm_Jobs`

I built out the MVC app with a `JobsController` and have the respective `Views` folder with `Create.cshtml`, `Delete.cshtml`, `Details.cshtml`, `Edit.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml`

I want to associate `mm_Profile` with a User.

After integrating the `ASPNET_MEMBERSHIP` Tables into my custom database, I added a `UserId` column of Type `uniqueidentifier` to `mm_Jobs` and created the proper foreign key relationship to `aspnet_Users` table (`FK_Jobs_aspnet_Users`)

I did so and now when I fill out my Jobs form (located in `Jobs -> Create.cshtml`) and press the submit button I get the following error :

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserId', table 'MovinMyStuff.dbo.Moves'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated
```

The line of code in my JobsController in my `Create()` method:

> Line: 52 db.SaveChanges();

How do I update my `Create()` to save change and associate the User with the Job, thus pushing the `UserId` into the `UserId` column in the `Jobs` table? The full create method is given below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Moves.Add(job);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(job);
    }
```

Comment: The info you've provided is a bit confusing: 1. The sql error is complaining about the UserId column on the Moves table, yet you're trying to insert a job? 2. What is mm_Table1 and mm_Table2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. I had an extra _Layout file in my Shared Folder within my Area. Apparantly, even upon hiding it the compiler will see this file.